# FCC Certification of same electronics in a different size enclosure

Tags: fcc

FCC Certification: I already obtained FCC Certification and Labels for a product. My question is: Do I need to apply for certification for a product which has the same electronics inside but the plastic case is slightly bigger? I wouldn't mind spending the money but the process was time consuming. Who should I contact in FCC for an approval if needed?

Comment: Is any shielding the same size?

Comment: Something about asking a barber if you need a haircut comes to mind.

Comment: I personally wouldn't do it again if we're talking plastic here.  You might be able to contact your test house who did the original cert (or a new one who can pull the cert).  They might tell you the same or maybe charge a smaller fee to just write up a new test report using the old data.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you probably don't need to have it re-tested.

Long answer: Testing requirements for changes to already certified devices are covered by the FCC's [permissive change](https://apps.fcc.gov/eas/comments/GetPublishedDocument.html?id=209&tn=904226) policy.

The re-test requirements for enclosure changes depend on the size of the changes. I would ask a TCB or the FCC directly to get confirmation for your specific case. It's a little subjective so you may get different answers from different sources.

I wrote an article called "[Is a design change without a re-test too risky](http://www.emcfastpass.com/how-risky-is-it-not-to-re-test-after-a-small-design-change/)" which covers the case in much more detail.